# ¿Como obtener números multiplicados al cuadrado que se encuentran dentro de un array en java?

Tags: java

Estoy recorriendo numeros dentro de un array.
java

```
int x;

    int [] array  = {1,2,5,4};
    for(int i = 0;i < array.length;i++) {
        x = (int)(Math.pow(i,2));

        System.out.print(x+",");
```

lo hize en python de la misma forma y funciona.

```
def numbers(lista):
for i in lista:
    x = i**2
    print(x,end = ",")
numbers([1,2,5,4])
```

no entiendo porque en java no multiplica los valores dentro del array si no sus pocisiones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En java te está multiplicando la posición porque le estas pasando como primer parámetro del metodo Math.pow la i, debes tener en cuenta que al pasarle la i le estas diciendo que eleve al cuadrado el valor de la posición, mas no el elemento del array que se encuentre en la posición i. Prueba reemplazando la primera instrucción dentro del for por esto:

```
x = (int)(Math.pow(array[i],2)); // ahi le estas indicando que eleve al cuadrado
                                 // el dato que se encuentre en la posición i del array
```

Comment: muy amable gracias :)